# How to store JavaRDD as a sequence file using spark java API?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to store JavaRDD as a sequence file instead of textfile. But i don't see any Java API for that. Is there a way for this? Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Just use Scala :) You will make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `JavaPairRDD` has a method `.saveAsSequenceFile` if not I think you can use `.saveAsHadoopFile` and have `SequenceFileOutputFormat.class` as the format param.  It seems to be explained a bit here: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-SequenceFile-Java-API-Repeat-Key-Values-td353.html

Comment: Thanks @samthebest for pointing this approach, but I tried and faced with an issue, here's my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44187041/could-not-find-a-serializer-for-the-value-class-org-apache-hadoop-hbase-client?noredirect=1#comment78584021_44187041, do you have any ideas please?