# Could not find a serializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, serialization, hbase

I'm trying to read data out of HBase and save it as a sequenceFile, but getting

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find a serializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're usingcustom serialization.
```

error.

I saw two similar posts:

[hadoop writables NotSerializableException with Apache Spark API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876681/hadoop-writables-notserializableexception-with-apache-spark-api)

and

[Spark HBase Join Error: object not serializable class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281538/spark-hbase-join-error-object-not-serializable-class-org-apache-hadoop-hbase-c)

Following those two posts, I registered Kyro classes with three classes, but still no luck.

Here's my program:

```
        String tableName = "validatorTableSample";
        System.out.println("Start indexing hbase: " + tableName);
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseRead");
        Class[] classes = {org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable.class, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.class, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result.class};
        sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(classes);
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName);
//      conf.setStrings("io.serializations",
//          conf.get("io.serializations"),
//          MutationSerialization.class.getName(),
//          ResultSerialization.class.getName());
        conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");

        JavaPairRDD<ImmutableBytesWritable, Result> hBasePairRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
            conf,
            TableInputFormat.class,
            ImmutableBytesWritable.class,
            Result.class);

        hBasePairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("/tmp/tempOutputPath", ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class, SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
        System.out.println("Finished readFromHbaseAndSaveAsSequenceFile() .........");
```

Here's the error stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find a serializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're usingcustom serialization.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getSequenceWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/05/25 10:58:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.io.IOException: Could not find a serializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're usingcustom serialization.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getSequenceWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/05/25 10:58:38 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
```

Comment: Did you get your error resolved ?

Comment: No, I haven't, I'm still faced with this issue, any clues please?

Comment: I have posted and answer ..Please try that once ..It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is what was needed to make it work

Because we use HBase to store our data and this reducer outputs its result to HBase table, Hadoop is telling us that he doesn’t know how to serialize our data. That is why we need to help it. Inside setUp set the io.serializations variable

```
conf.setStrings("io.serializations", new String[]{hbaseConf.get("io.serializations"), MutationSerialization.class.getName(), ResultSerialization.class.getName()});
```

Answer (score 0):

> the code already pass the test

```
object HbaseDataExport extends LoggingTime{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val con = SparkConfig.getProperties()
    val sparkConf = SparkConfig.getSparkConf()
    val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    config.setStrings("io.serializations",
      config.get("io.serializations"),
      "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MutationSerialization",
      "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ResultSerialization")
    val path = "/Users/jhTian/Desktop/hbaseTimeData/part-m-00030"
    val path1 = "hdfs://localhost:9000/hbaseTimeData/part-m-00030"

    sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path1, classOf[SequenceFileInputFormat[Text, Result]], classOf[Text], classOf[Result], config).foreach(x => {
      import collection.JavaConversions._
      for (i <- x._2.listCells) {
        logger.info(s"family:${Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneFamily(i))},qualifier:${Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneQualifier(i))},value:${Bytes.toString(CellUtil.cloneValue(i))}")
      }
    })
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```